# Custom SuperTheme XML in Powerpoint

Tags: xml, themes, ms-office, powerpoint-2016

In our Windows Office 365 environment we've embarked on building "SuperTheme" for Powerpoint, editing the XML, so we can have different designs for different sizes of output, some pptx being solely printed on A4, others being 16x9 screen only presentations.

We need a simple SuperTheme with only 1 set of colors, but 2 different designs, swapped via the change size button on the ribbon.

Looking at an unzipped supertheme thmx file there is a theme in the base folder, and a variants folder, containing each of the variant themes.

Do I have to duplicate the theme in my case, ie I have the 16x9 theme in the base folder, then the 16x9 theme again and 4x3 theme in the variants folder?

How does Powerpoint choose which is the default to apply when the theme is initially chosen?

Comment: There's virtually no documentation on SuperThemes from Microsoft. You may have to derive answers to some of your questions by testing your own themes. If you decide you need help from someone who's worked with SuperThemes extensively, visit echosvoice.com and get in contact with Echo Swinford. Disclosure: she's a friend and colleague.